# Upscale Precipitation

Tags: r

I have a data of `c(32, 32)` array which is 0.2 by 0.2 grid resolution. I want to decrease the resolution 0.4 by 0.4 grid resolution  which is to be `c(16, 16)` array, again 0.8 by 0.8 grid resolution which is become `c(8, 8)` array.

I develop the following script only for the first `c(16, 16)` array but it add only the diagonal term 
  `a=c(32,32)`

```
# define array

ra <- array(NA, c(16, 16))

n=0


k=0

for  ( i in seq(1,32,2)) {

       for (j in seq(1,32,2)){
            ra[n,k]=sum(a[i:(i+1),j:(j+1)])
       }
    n=n+1
 k=k+1

}
```

Thank you very much I am looking forward who solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your approach:

```
a <- array(runif(32 * 32), c(32, 32))
ra <- array(NA, c(16, 16))

n <- 1
for(i in seq(1, 32, 2)){
    k <- 1
    for(j in seq(1, 32, 2)){
        ra[n, k] <- sum(a[i:(i+1), j:(j+1)])
        k <- k + 1
    }
    n <- n + 1
}
```

Sure there are more elegant alternatives.